# Implementation of Kallmann's Dynamic Constrained Delaunay Triangulation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, open-source, triangulation, delaunay

Does anyone know of any open source implementation (preferably in java) of Kallmann's DCDT algorithm? If there's another DCDT algorithm that has been implemented, that may work as well. I wasn't sure if I should post this here or on CSTheory StackExchange, so let me know if this is the wrong place to post.

EDIT: Here's the algorithm: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/100269/files/Kallmann_and_al_Geometric_Modeling_03.pdf

Comment: CSTheory, and due to it's rarity I doubt you will find more than the psuedo-code (sections 4 and 5 of that paper). Unless you attempt to code it yourself and post your code when you get stuck.

Comment: I'm going to have to find code or implement it myself unfortunately. I'm planning on releasing the code tho so if you want it, I'll post it when I find it / finish it.

Comment: Yeah looks like a pretty useful algorithm, I look forward to seeing your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He keeps the source code on his web page: http://graphics.ucmerced.edu/software/tripath/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no great difference between the DCDT algorithm from Kallmann, and the implementation in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). At the functionality level, at least: CGAL 2D CDT are as dynamic as the DCDT from Kallmann.

CGAL also has Java bindings, via the [cgal-bindings project](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/), and the 2D CDT data structure is wrapped.